# php application Gitlab branches url override

Tags: javascript, php, gitlab

Our company is doing a project which backend is php.

Our CI/CD setting is using gitlab pipeline.

So when we make a micro-branch, the micro-branch will generate a subdomain and deploy the application to a space with the generated subdomain attached.

The current problem we are facing is when the application is deployed, some constants in both js and php part need to be modified.

what's the standard way or good practice to change constants in both js and php part.

Please help and thank you for the help in advance

Comment: A standard way is to use environment variables. With PHP it's easy _(look it up, I'm sure you'll find how to)_, but with front-end JS, it depends. Is it "static" JS files you are serving? Also, how are you deploying? Do you use Docker, a real machine, ... ?

Comment: hello blex, thank you for the quick reply. what we are doing right now is to use a yml file to change the constants in php file(we are using a php framework, so we used the yml to change the constants in the php framework config file). we also did the similar thing in the js file too. But I got some suggestions that the constants in static js file should come from php file instead of being modified by yml file.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'm also not a fan of modifying files automatically after a deploy just to get your config in there (even with PHP). Your code should be independent of configuration (principle of Separation of Concerns). Sometimes it's not easy though. The way I would find the cleanest would be to have your config as environment variables. Then, PHP can access them easily with `$_ENV`. And I would have a `config.js.php` file containing `window.config = <?=json_encode(["host" => $_ENV["host"], ...])?>;` and include that file as a `<script>` in every page that needs it

Comment: these micro-branches have been deployed into docker instances in digital ocean

Comment: thank you very much blex, your solution sounds perfect for our case :)